# Is it a good idea to wrap NgRx actions, effects, selectors and reducer inside a class?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, state-management

I'm currently learning `NgRx`. One thing I noticed in tutorials, documentation, and various articles is that usually store components are placed in different ts files (actions are created in one ts file, effects is a class and in its own ts file, and so on) just like how it is taught here: https://ngrx.io/guide/store.

My concern with this approach is if I have a very large application with so many folders, wouldn't that make it difficult to track all store components and figure out which effect or reducer is subscribed to an action? I understand that there are available dev tools that can help visualize the actions happening in a store, but I'm more concerned with how to organize store components in an Angular project.

That being said, what if I just wrap everything in one class so I can easily track all store components? Will it make my store unscalable and even more difficult to maintain as my application grow? Here's a sample code to see what I mean:

```js
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { createAction, Store, props, createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Person } from "./person.model";
import { PersonService } from "./person.service";
import { map, mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class PersonStore {

  // Selectors
  get hasPeople$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select(({ person }) => person.people.length > 0);
  }

  get people$(): Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.store.select(({ person }) => person.people);
  }

  constructor(
    private readonly store: Store<{ person: PersonState }>,
    private readonly actions$: Actions,
    private readonly personService: PersonService
  ) {
  }

  initializePeople(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(PersonStore.getPeopleAction());
  }

  deletePersonById(id: number): void {
    this.store.dispatch(PersonStore.deletePersonByIdAction({ id }));
  }

  //--- Actions, reducer, and effects
  private static readonly source: string = '[Person store]';

  // Actions
  private static readonly getPeopleAction = createAction(`${PersonStore.source} Get people`);
  private static readonly setPeopleAction = createAction(
    `${PersonStore.source} Set people`, 
    props<{ people: Person[] }>()
  );

  private static readonly deletePersonByIdAction = createAction(
    `${PersonStore.source} Delete person by ID`,
    props<{ id: number }>()
  );

  private static readonly removePersonByIdAction = createAction(
    `${PersonStore.source} Remove person from state by ID`,
    props<{ id: number }>()
  );

  // Reducer
  static get reducer() {
    return createReducer(
      initialPersonState,
      on(PersonStore.setPeopleAction, (_ , { people }) => ({ people })),
      on(PersonStore.removePersonByIdAction, (state, { id }) => ({ ...state, people: state.people.filter(x => x.id !== id) }))
    );
  }

  // Effects
  private readonly initializePeople$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(PersonStore.getPeopleAction),
    mergeMap(() => this.personService.getPeople().pipe(
      map(people => PersonStore.setPeopleAction({ people }))
    ))
  ));

  private readonly deletePersonById$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(PersonStore.deletePersonByIdAction),
    mergeMap(action => this.personService.deletePersonBy(action.id).pipe(
      map(id => PersonStore.removePersonByIdAction({ id }))
    ))
  ));
}

interface PersonState {
  people: Person[];
}

const initialPersonState: PersonState = {
  people: []
};
```

Then in my component, I just need to inject `PersonStore` and use it like this:

```
// Set selector observable to my component property
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.people$ = this.personStore.people$.pipe(/* do some transformation here */);
}

// Delete a person
deletePersonById(id: number): void {
  this.personStore.deletePersonById(id);
}
```

Comment: You can but with the tradeoff reduced tree shakeability.

Comment: @Eldar, I don't know what tree shaking is. How is it going to affect tree shakeability? Could you give an example?

Comment: The examples you saw were exporting parts of the state, selectors, and actions as separate exports so that unused ones can be trimmed in the build phase so that your application bundle size is reduced. If you bundle them in a class when you import the class every part of it will be part of your bundle.